# How to restrict Azure Maps Key to a domain name?

Tags: azure-maps

I have created a key on Azure Maps, and used it on a html page to view a map.
But anyone can see my map api key if they view source of the page.
So, if a person have my key, they can use it on their website.
As you know this service is a paid service, no one wants their bill go high.

How can I restrict my Azure Maps Key use to a specific domain name?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Maps now provides a higher security option via Azure Active Directory which can be used instead of a key: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/azure-maps-authentication This can be used in both public and private applications.

Comment: Can you please explain the steps . i couldn't understand the documentation

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to implement Azure Active Directory depending on your scenario (public facing website, user login site...). The basic flow consists of having a service that retrieves a token from your account that has a time constraint on it. You would have this service locked down so that only your app can access it. Alternatively, a security certificate can be used on your site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Azure Maps allows you to restrict API keys to specific domains currently.

And even though Google and Bing both provide domain restriction for API keys it's not a full proof solution. Someone can still spoof your domain by forging the HTTP Referer header - See [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15696/google-custom-search-engine-api-key-is-it-confidential).

So, ideally for full security (especially for paid accounts) you wanna do one of the following:

1: Have a light-weight back-end proxy for your app. Your front-end app/client calls your back-end (which can be a simple Node.js app) which first validates the client (up to you how to handle that) and simply passes the call to Azure Maps and gives the response back to the client. This way the key is actually stored in the back-end which uses it to make calls to Azure.

2: You can also think about storing your API keys in Azure KeyVault and fetch them at runtime. [Here's](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/key-vault-node-getting-started/#index) a sample if you're interested.

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you so much for your reply and 2 options for my question. I think I can test out the 2nd option. But I think if there is key restrictions part in Azure Dashboard, and I can set allow only from an Ip address it would be much more optimal way to secure my key. Because in that way I will not need to do all the same keyvault implimantion on several pages. This check should be done on server side on your api servers.

Comment: Sure, if the service provided IP address (not domain) restriction then it'll be a little simpler but I don't think it does as of today. I still think it's a very restrictive solution. With KeyVault (or any similar solutions) you fetch the key once at application start and keep it in a variable that can be accessed from anywhere within the application. You can also rotate your keys at regular intervals. I see your point but as of today there is no one click solution to this problem - The KeyVault solution is not that much work though - just give it a try.